# How can I format the numbers in viewrecord on jqgrid pager?

Tags: formatting, jqgrid, pager, number-formatting

When a large number of pages are present, the format of the numbers in the pager is "11 223" but I would like it to be "11,223"

View 11 026 - 11 031 of 11 031

should be

View 11,026 - 11,031 of 11,031

I searched the documentation for JQGrid but couldn't find a way to do this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can set

```
$.jgrid.formatter.integer.thousandsSeparator=',';
```

or modify in the grid.locale-en.js file (or another locale file which you use) the line 90

```
integer : {thousandsSeparator: " ", defaultValue: '0'},
```

(in the minimized version you should search for `integer:{thousandsSeparator:" "`) to the line

```
integer : {thousandsSeparator: ",", defaultValue: '0'},
```

By the way, you can of cause set also `$.jgrid.formatter.integer.thousandsSeparator=''`, then it will be no thousand separator: instead of "11 223" you will have "11223" and not "11,223".